# Is it possible to find the operations (+, -, etc.) of an equation given a sum and values?

Tags: arithmetic

1 + 2 + 3 = 6 is a pretty straight-forward equation, but let's say you have something like this:

1 ? 2 ? 3 = 6

Where you have all the individual data points and the target, can you find "calculate" what operations to use?

Comment: have you tried supervised statistical learning? Where you give them tons of equations and the operator is the classification as an output. I do have actually no idea what the purpose is of this question.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted other than being more or less unmotivated?  It could be important. The solution in general won't be unique, e.g. $4 ? 2 ? 1 ? 1 = 4$.  Question to think about: how many solutions exist for a given set of numbers and what they equal? Brute force, you could enumerate all of the $2^N$ possibilities where $N$ is the number of operations unknown, assuming only $+$ and $-$.  But I'm sure there are more refined ways to approach the matter.  For example, $8 ? 8 ? 8 ? 4 = -4$ is less than zero, and therefore neither operation on the $8$'s could be positive.

Comment: I would expect that this would be an [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) question when properly generalized.  It is easy to check if a solution is valid, but much harder to generate a solution for the general case.

Comment: @Merkh ${8-8\over 8}-4$ or $8\cdot(8-8)-4$. but $-2$ can be done with ${8+8\over 8}-4$ disproving your whole argument.

Comment: Read: "...assuming only + and -"

Comment: If we wanted to consider multiplication and so on, I'm sure there is *still* a more refined way than trying all possibilities.  The search space may still be combinatorial in size, but I expect that certain operations, like using multiplication for two of the ? marks in my example, will be disallowed.  Are parenthesis allowed? Exponentiation? Of course the question itself needs refinement, if we are to disprove each other's general observations.